# What is the correct way to access a blueprint class component in C++

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint, unrealscript

I recently switched from unity and I wanted to know if there was a “getComponent” equivalent in UE4? I have an enemy script and I created a blueprint from that script and have added a widget with a progress bar to show the enemies health during combat. I have seen a lot of examples of how to do this in blueprint but if possible, I would like to just do it in code and let the percentage be calculated when it is needed to be, like after damage or something, rather than binding via blueprints.

I have tried using the getcomponentbyclass method but that throws an error because the component I want is not a child of the actor class.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `GetComponentByClass()` on an `Actor`.
If your `Enemy` is a Component, you can call `getOwner()` to retrieve the actor owning this component.
You can then call `GetComponentByClass()` on this actor instance.

Comment: I tried to upvote this but my reputation is too low so I’ll just say thank you for the clear answer.

Comment: To add to that, you can also use template method [FindComponentByClass](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/API/Runtime/Engine/GameFramework/AActor/FindComponentByClass/2/index.html) which will automatically cast to the type that you requested.